# I need an exact reference for a hadith in Musnad Ahmed!

Tags: hadith, reference-request

I need the exact reference of following hadith in Musnad Imam Ahmed. I saw one reference in this link [Hadith link](http://www.ahlalhdeeth.com/vbe/forum/hadeeth-sciences-islamic-history/15150-need-to-know-the-classification-of-a-hadith-from-musnad-ahmad-dinar-dirham) but while I search with hadith number, I couldn't find in books. I search several publication from Archive.org but no where this hadith was mentioned according to the number in above link.

Can any one help me to find the hadith location (exact) in Musnad ahmed.
The hadith is as follows:

> "A time is certainly coming over mankind in which there will be nothing [left] which will be of use save a dinar and a dirham."

Answer (score 2):

The Arabic text given on your linked site is:

#### ليأتين على الناس زمان لا ينفع فيه إلا الدينار و الدرهم

The hadith number will vary with the publisher, and it is possible that some publications are not available online at all. It may be easier to refer to it through chapter names: This hadith is from the sub-musnad **مسند الشاميين** in the section of the sahabi  **المقدام بن معدي كرب**, near the end of that section.

It is listed under number 16867 on [islamweb](http://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?bk_no=121&pid=61109&hid=16867).

It is number 17201 in these editions from [Darussalam](https://archive.org/details/FP155502/page/n1198), [Al-Resalah](https://archive.org/stream/waqmsnda/msnda28#page/n432/mode/2up) and others.

It is number 17135 in this edition from [Darul Hadith Cairo](https://archive.org/stream/WAQmusndaWAQ/musnda13#page/n298/mode/2up).

It is number 17664 in this edition from [Dar Al-Kotob Al-Ilmiyah](https://archive.org/stream/waq88061/07_88067#page/n149/mode/2up).